# Input Error in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I developed an application in android. Its input fields are working fine e.g. username and password inputs (this will call the services and get a xml response) in 2.2, 2.3 but it does not work in 4.0, 4.1.

**xml**

```
EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
```

in error log.

```
  Url is not found
```

(in catch exception..)

**edit**

android 4.1 sdk and updated eclipse log cat was printing lot

```
07-03 11:57:07.826: I/Choreographer(2747): Skipped 44 frames! 
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

by that I can't easily find error on Log cat.

error was:

```
07-03 11:58:25.927: E/ActivityThread(555): Failed to find provider info
for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack 07-03 11:58:25.947:
E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(555): Could not find a dictionary pack
```

Comment: paste the exception stack trace

Comment: okay i will accept the answers,, but in android 4.1 sdk and updated eclipse log cat was printing lot (like 07-03 11:57:07.826: I/Choreographer(2747): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
).. by that i can't easily find error on Log cat.

Comment: the error was:    07-03 11:58:25.927: E/ActivityThread(555): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
07-03 11:58:25.947: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(555): Could not find a dictionary pack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if it is working fine on android 2.2 & 2.3 OSs, then the error may be due to the more strict network policies in android 4.0. Adding the below static block in your activity/communication-class will remove the communication policy related issues in 4.0

```
static{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: it's working sunil,Thank u very much and how to accept this in stack over flow..am new user here