# Someone help me. I got this problem after recompile with API

Tags: java, adapter, android-adapter

Hello so this is my code, somehow i still get error down there i described error , any help would be appreciated, I am not really expert with import of this and especially emulator itself.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodViewHolder>{
//1st error on this line (MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:17)

private Context mContext;
private List<FoodData> myFoodList;

public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<FoodData> myFoodList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.myFoodList = myFoodList;
}

@Override
public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item,viewGroup,false);

    return new  FoodViewHolder(mView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder, int i) {

    foodViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myFoodList.get(i).getItemImage());
// 2nd error on this line (MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:39)

    foodViewHolder.mTitle.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemName());
 foodViewHolder.mDescription.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemDescription());
    foodViewHolder.mPrice.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemPrice());

    foodViewHolder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Image",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemImage());
            intent.putExtra("Description",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemDescription());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myFoodList.size();
  }
}


class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


ImageView imageView;
TextView mTitle , mDescription, mPrice;
CardView mCardView;


public FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    mPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);

    mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myCardView);

   }
}
```

Hello guys I'm beginner in android studio .someone tell me how can i solve this error's .
thanks in advance.

// Errors

```
03-10 08:14:36.172 59-59/? E/baseband-redis: Redis baseband write connect error: Connection refused

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
03-10 08:14:36.276 59-59/? E/baseband-redis: Redis baseband write connect error: Connection refused
03-10 08:14:36.376 59-59/? E/baseband-redis: Redis baseband write connect error: Connection refused
03-10 08:14:36.480 59-59/? E/baseband-redis: cannot connect, exit
03-10 08:14:37.876 192-192/? E/network_profile_handler: init_all_network_profile_state: wlan: eth1 `phone:rmnet0`
03-10 08:14:49.644 192-380/? E/network_profile_handler: Error. network interface data NULL
03-10 08:14:52.424 199-199/? E/PhonePolicy: Could not preload class for phone policy: 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
03-10 08:14:52.452 390-390/? E/setdpi: Setting DPI to 320
03-10 08:14:52.984 381-382/? E/SurfaceFlinger: setOrientation with orientation=0
03-10 08:14:52.984 381-382/? E/SurfaceFlinger: setOrientation orientation=0
03-10 08:14:52.984 381-382/? E/FramebufferNativeWindow: setOrientation with fbDev=0xb8eec2b8 fbDev-
>setOrientation=0x0 orientation=0
03-10 08:14:55.764 408-408/system_process E/BatteryService: usbOnlinePath not found
03-10 08:14:55.764 408-408/system_process E/BatteryService: batteryHealthPath not found
03-10 08:14:55.764 408-408/system_process E/BatteryService: batteryTemperaturePath not found
03-10 08:15:03.056 408-460/system_process E/libsuspend: Error opening /sys/power/autosleep: No such file or directory
03-10 08:15:03.056 408-460/system_process E/libsuspend: Error opening /sys/power/wakeup_count: Permission denied
03-10 08:15:03.056 408-460/system_process E/libsuspend: failed to initialize autosuspend
03-10 08:15:03.408 201-433/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:03.604 408-468/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
03-10 08:15:03.760 408-468/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
03-10 08:15:03.776 201-201/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:03.860 408-468/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
03-10 08:15:03.916 408-425/system_process E/MobileDataStateTracker: default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
03-10 08:15:03.916 408-425/system_process E/MobileDataStateTracker: default: Could not enable APN type "default"
03-10 08:15:03.932 408-493/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to reload STA firmware java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '2 softap fwreload eth1 STA' failed with '400 2 Softap operation failed (Success)'
03-10 08:15:03.940 408-503/system_process E/WifiHW: Unable to open connection to supplicant on "eth1": No such file or directory
03-10 08:15:05.388 408-493/system_process E/WifiConfigStore: Error parsing configurationjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-10 08:15:05.408 408-493/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to set country code us
03-10 08:15:05.408 408-493/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to set frequency band 0
03-10 08:15:05.976 408-654/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in agps_data_conn_open
03-10 08:15:07.128 568-687/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
03-10 08:15:07.132 568-687/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/BinaryDictionaryGetter: Could not find a dictionary pack
03-10 08:15:07.988 408-495/system_process E/ConnectivityService: no dns provided for WIFI - using 8.8.8.8
03-10 08:15:07.992 408-495/system_process E/ConnectivityService: exception setting default dns interface: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: command '10 resolver setifdns eth1' failed with '500 10 Wrong number of arguments to resolver setifdns'
03-10 08:15:09.520 408-493/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: Failed to set country code us
03-10 08:15:10.500 201-201/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:10.600 201-433/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:10.836 201-201/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:10.924 201-433/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:11.156 201-201/? E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so
03-10 08:15:29.628 381-382/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 716352 bytes, got 30660 
03-10 08:15:29.628 381-382/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 685692 bytes, got 39420
03-10 08:15:29.628 381-382/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 646272 bytes, got 43800
03-10 08:15:29.636 381-382/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 602472 bytes, got 143080 
03-10 08:15:29.652 381-382/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 459392 bytes, got 153300
03-10 08:15:29.652 381-382/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 306092 bytes, got 161920 
03-10 08:15:30.716 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
03-10 08:15:30.716 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
03-10 08:15:30.764 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
03-10 08:15:30.772 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
03-10 08:15:30.784 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
03-10 08:15:30.936 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
03-10 08:15:30.996 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
03-10 08:15:31.980 1050-1050/? E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 33177612-byte allocation.
03-10 08:15:32.108 1050-1050/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1050 (deshtourstplace)
03-10 08:15:34.584 408-467/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '537d5654 com.allexamquestions.xyz.himachalpradeshtourstplace/com.allexamquestions.xyz.himachalpradeshtourstplace.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305388/input-error-in-android

Answer (score 0):

`public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodViewHolder>{`

replace with

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.FoodViewHolder>{
```

Answer (score 0):

> //1st error on this line
>   (MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:17)

You have to initialize the constructor of RecyclerView.Adapter. By calling super(); you override the constructor.

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodViewHolder>{
//1st error on this line (MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:17)

private Context mContext;
private List<FoodData> myFoodList;

public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<FoodData> myFoodList) {
    super();
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.myFoodList = myFoodList;
}

...

}
```